"Heap corruption detected" error while Allocating memory inside constructor
I am currently implementing skiplist with my own vector implementation and I am getting an heap corruption not detected error
testing skiplist
entered Skiplist constructor
Skiplist: success creating pSentinel
Skiplist: success creating pHeader
Skiplist: pHeader()->levels() == 4
Skiplist: success constructing
***success: testing skiplist

testing node creation
try creating Skiplist<int> testNodeCreation
entered Skiplist constructor
Test_Skiplist(70815,0x7ff8457d7100) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x6000005f01a0
*** Incorrect guard value: 105553167581712
Test_Skiplist(70815,0x7ff8457d7100) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./bin/src/test/Test_Skiplist

when running
int main() {
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"testing skiplist"<<std::endl;
    Skiplist<int> sk1;
    std::cout<<"***success: testing skiplist"<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<std::endl<<"testing node creation"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"try creating Skiplist<int> testNodeCreation"<<std::endl;
    Skiplist<int> testNodeCreation;
    std::cout<<"created Skiplist<int>"<<std::endl;
}

My understanding is that heat corruption error is thrown when I try to access out of bounds of heap allocated memory.
However, it seems like the error occurs right after second iteration of operator new + Skiplist<T>::Node::Node() constructor call:
template<typename T>
Skiplist<T>::Skiplist() {
    std::cout<<"entered Skiplist constructor"<<std::endl;
    using Node = typename Skiplist<T>::Node;

    this->pSentinel = new Node(*this, 4);
    /*(typename Skiplist<T>::Node *) this->pSentinel = new Node(*this, 4);*/   /* Skiplist<T>::Node* sentinel  */
    std::cout<<"Skiplist: success creating pSentinel"<<std::endl;

    this->pHeader = new Node(*this, 4);
    /*(typename Skiplist<T>::Node *) this->pHeader = new Node(*this, 4);*/     /* Skiplist<T>::Node* header  */
    std::cout<<"Skiplist: success creating pHeader"<<std::endl;

    
    std::cout<<"Skiplist: pHeader()->levels() == "<<pHeader->levels()<<std::endl;
    int inx = this->pHeader->levels() - 1;
    for(; inx>=0; --inx) {
        (*pHeader)[inx] = pSentinel; /* typeof Node * */
    }


    std::srand(std::time(0));   /* seeding std::rand() */
    std::cout<<"Skiplist: success constructing"<<std::endl;
}

Looking at the first round of Skiplist<T>::Skiplist constructor call stdout value, it seemes like
pHeader()->levels()

is providing the proper output 4 and therefore the for loop in the Skiplist<T>::Skiplist constructor should be within the proper index range, and that is probably why the first iteration of Skiplist<T>::Skiplist constructor call does not fail, successfully connecting the header node to the sentinel node of the skiplist.
Node constructor
template<typename T>
Skiplist<T>::Node::Node(Skiplist<T>& sk, size_t __levels) : skiplist(sk) {
    this->listToNext = Vector<Skiplist<T>::Node*>(__levels, nullptr);
    /* no val initialized */
    if(skiplist.allowedMaxLevel <= __levels){
        skiplist.allowedMaxLevel = __levels + 1;
    }   
}

constructs a statically allocated Skiplist<T>::Node which contains the reference to the skiplist containing itself, a personally implemented vector, and a value.
The unary operator[] for Skiplist<T>::Node is implemented as
template<typename T>
Skiplist<T>::Node * & Skiplist<T>::Node::operator[](const size_t i) {
    return listToNext.at(i);    /* listToNext : Vector<Node*> */
}

which therefore is intended to return the Skiplist<T>::Node* pointer value.
The vector
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(size_t  size, const T& val) {
    this->vsize = size;
    set_appropriate_capacity();

    this->container = (T *)std::malloc((this->vcapacity) * sizeof(T));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        container[i] = val;
    }
}

itself is static, which includes a dynamically allocated container in it.
The .at() member function of Vector<T> which is used to implement Skiplist<T>::Node::operator[] is implemented as
template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](size_t i) {
    return this->container[i];
}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::at(size_t i) {
    if(i>=this->vsize)
        throw("Vector::at() index out of bounds");
    return this->container[i];
}

with rest of the functions used in the vector constructor being
template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator=(Vector<T> && vec) {
    vsize = vec.vsize;
    vcapacity = vec.vcapacity;
    container = vec.container;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector() {
    this->vsize = 0;
    std::free(this->container);
    this->vcapacity = 0;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::set_appropriate_capacity() {
    size_t capacity_candidate = 25;

    
    /*
    prevent overflow
    REQUIRES: this->vsize is of type size_t (ensured by def)
              (probably also works when max_size is odd)
    */
    const size_t max_size = -1;   /*signed -1 is unsigned max*/
    if((max_size/2 - 10 < this->vsize) 
                        && (this->vsize <= max_size)){
        this->vcapacity = max_size;
    }

    while((capacity_candidate - 10) < this->vsize) {
        capacity_candidate *= 2;
    }
    this->vcapacity = capacity_candidate;
}

When I have tested the Vector<T> implementation, there has been no problem with the heap regardless of how many vectors I have created. Therefore I suppose that the problem is not about the Vector<T> implementation.
I have tried using lldb and it seems like the error is from malloc which doesn't seem to make sense considering it's a Heap corruption detected error
(lldb) s
Process 75063 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x0000000100002a35 Test_Skiplist`Vector<Skiplist<int>::Node*>::Vector(this=0x0000600003a08060) at vector.tpp:11:47
   8        this->vsize = 0;
   9        set_appropriate_capacity();
   10   
-> 11       this->container = (T *)std::malloc((this->vcapacity) * sizeof(T));
   12   }
   13   
   14   template<typename T>
(lldb) s
Test_Skiplist(75063,0x7ff8457d7100) malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x600000f001a0
*** Incorrect guard value: 105553177116672
Test_Skiplist(75063,0x7ff8457d7100) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Process 75063 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007ff80226d14a libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
->  0x7ff80226d14a <+10>: jae    0x7ff80226d154 ; <+20>
    0x7ff80226d14c <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7ff80226d14f <+15>: jmp    0x7ff802266b20 ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7ff80226d154 <+20>: retq   

Are there some other potential reasons why an Heap corruption detected error might occur? Is my use of operator new wrong in any way? Thank you in advance.
#ifndef Skiplist_Included
#define Skiplist_Included

#include "vector.hpp"
#include <cstddef> /* size_t */
#include <cstdlib> /* rand() */

template<typename T>
class Skiplist {
private:
    size_t allowedMaxLevel;    /* Inner class is a friend of the class it is defined within */
                                /* Outer::Inner class can access the (private) member variable of Outer */

    bool flipcoin();

public:

    class Node {
    private:
        Vector<Node *> listToNext;
        Skiplist& skiplist;

    public:
        Node(Skiplist& sk);
        Node(Skiplist& sk, size_t __levels);
        Node(Skiplist& sk, size_t __levels, T __key);
        /*
        Node(Node& n);
        Node& operator=(Node& n);
        */
        Node(Node&& n); /* want to use default move constructor */
        /*
        Node& operator=(Node&& n);
        */

        T key;

        /* void updateMaxNumOfLevels(); */
        const size_t levels();
        Node* & operator[](const size_t i);
        void addLevel(const size_t i);
    };
private:
    Node* pHeader;
    Node* pSentinel;

    void insertBetween(Node* pFrontNode, Node* pBackNode, Node* pNodeToInsert);
    void insertImpl(Node* pCurrNode, Node* pNodeToInsert, size_t topLevel);
public:
    Skiplist();
    /* ~Skiplist(); */


    /* bool isNextNodeSentinel(Node* pCurrNode); */
    void insert(T __key);
};

/*--------------------------------------------*/




/*--------------------------------------------*/
#include "skiplist.tpp"


#endif

#ifndef Vector_Included
#define Vector_Included

#include<cstdlib>  /* for size_t, memory alloc */
#include<iterator> /* for std::random_access_iterator_tag */
#include<cstddef>  /* for ptrdiff_t */

template<typename T>
class Vector {
    T * container;
    size_t vsize, vcapacity;
    /* size_t iter; */

    void set_appropriate_capacity();
    

public:
    /* Constructors */
    Vector();
    Vector(size_t size);
    Vector(size_t  size, const T& val);
    template<size_t N>
    Vector(const T(&arr)[N]);
    Vector& operator=(Vector& vec);
    Vector(Vector<T>&& vec);
    Vector& operator=(Vector&& vec);
    /* Destructor */
    ~Vector();

    T& operator[](size_t i);
    T& operator[](size_t i) const;
    T& at(size_t i);
    /* const T& at(size_t i) const; */
    T& front();
    T& back();
    void sort(size_t lo, size_t hi);
    
    

    const size_t& capacity();
    const size_t& size();
    void print_container();

    struct Iterator {
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        Iterator(); /* default construct */
        Iterator(const Vector<T>* other_vp); /* construct */
        Iterator(const Vector<T>* other_vp, size_t other_inx); /* construct */
        Iterator(const Iterator & other_iter); /* copy construct */
        Iterator operator=(const Iterator & other_iter); /* copy assign */
        /* destruct - use default : declaring default destructor causes error */

        reference operator*(); /* dereference operator: *Iter */
        reference operator*() const; 
        pointer operator&(); /* address_of operator: &Iter */
        /* const pointer operator&() const; */
        reference operator[](difference_type n); /* dereference n index away from current */
        /* const reference operator[](difference_type n) const; */
        
        /* change inx value of *this iterator, return some iterator */
        Iterator& operator++(); /* prefix ++ on Iterator, return ++'d one */
        Iterator operator++(int); /* postfix ++ on Iterator, return non++'d one */
        Iterator& operator--(); /* prefix -- on Iterator, return --'d one */
        Iterator operator--(int); /* postfix -- on Iterator, return non--'d one*/


        Iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n); /* shift *this iter, return *this */

        Iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& n); /* shift *this iter, return *this */
        Iterator operator+(const difference_type& n); /* return new shifted iter, *this no change */
        Iterator operator-(const difference_type& n); /* return new shifted iter, *this no change */

        /*---------------*/
        difference_type operator-(const Iterator& j); /* return difference between *this.inx and I2.inx */


        /* compare inx values between Iterators */
        bool operator==(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx == j.inx */
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx != j.inx */
        bool operator<(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx < j.inx */
        bool operator>(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx > j.inx */
        bool operator<=(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx <= j.inx */
        bool operator>=(const Iterator& j); /* *this.inx >= j.inx */
        
        void turn_invalid();
        bool is_invalid();

    private:
        const Vector<T>* vp;
        size_t inx;
        bool is_valid;
        void try_throw_invalid_iter_error();
    };

    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;

    Iterator insert(const Iterator & position_iter, size_t n, const T val);
    void pop_back();
    void push_back(const T& val);

};



template<typename T>
void swap(Vector<T>& v, const size_t i, const size_t j);

template<typename T>
size_t partition(Vector<T>& v, const size_t lo, const size_t pi, const size_t hi);

template<typename T>
void quicksort(Vector<T>& v, const size_t lo, const size_t hi);


/*---------------------------------------------------*/
#include"vector.tpp" 




#endif


The fastest way to track down memory issues (including heap corruption) is by using valgrind or building with address sanitizer enabled.

The "error" might be detected in the malloc function, but it's not the place where it happens. You're likely overwriting memory somewhere, going out of bounds and have undefined behavior. As suggested by @StephenNewell, use Valgrind or the sanitizer to find out more (build with -g -fsanitize=address,undefined).

On a very different note, all symbols beginning with double underscore (like for example __levels) are reserved and should not be defined in your own code. See e.g. What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier? for more information.

I am currently implementing skiplist with my own vector implementation -- For the time being, have you tested your skiplist class using a known working vector class, i.e. std::vector<T>?  That should have been the order of how you would have developed your classes -- use things that are guaranteed to work first so as to get SkipList working quickly, and then when you see things working, then you introduce (or attempt to introduce) home-made classes.

Your move assign operator ia actually doing a sallow copy. So you're going to end up with a double free somewhere which will corrupt your memory.

this->container = (T *)std::malloc((this->vcapacity) * sizeof(T)) -- This will not work if T is not trivially-copyable.  A Vector<std::string> for example, would make that line of code introduce undefined behavior.  So if this is your Vector class, it is easily breakable -- you just didn't instantiate it with a type T that would cause it to break.  Also, this emphasizes my previous comment -- if you had used std::vector and started with that, possibly you would have no issues since std::vector does not allocate memory this way (it uses placement-new).

I counted three bugs in Vector, Paul's mentioned one, the move constructor is also bugged and the set_appropriate_capacity function has a weird calculation which seems to do nothing. None of these bugs seem to affect the code you've presented however, although the move constructor would be a serious problem if it were ever used. What we really need is a proper [mre] instead of snippets of code.

I see jo-art also spotted the move constructor bug.

I would certainly replace Vector with std::vector in SkipList while you are fixing bugs. Vector has bugs, SkipList probably has bugs. Makes sense to debug one thing at a time.

@jo-art But isn't doing a shallow copy the point of move assignment? The rvalue object would disappear right after the move assignment operation and what I need to do is pass dynamic mem pointer?

int main() { Vector<int> v1(1,0);  Vector<int> v2;  v1 = std::move(v2); } -- int main() { Vector<std::string> v1(1, std::string(100, 'x')); } -- Probably broke your Vector class with these two simple main programs.

@jho317 -- But isn't doing a shallow copy the point of move assignment? -- You are also supposed to make the passed-in object "useless", and you didn't do that.  What I mean by "useless" is that if it is destroyed, it shouldn't affect the object you are moving to.  Your move constructor is missing: vec.container = nullptr;.

@jho317 After doing your move construction you are going to have two objects with the same pointer to allocated memory. That's a recipe for a double free and heap corruption. Nothing 'disappears' during a move operation, you have to write the code for that.

@PaulMcKenzie I added vec.container = nullptr; to the move assignment and all the memory error disappeared, and I can even insert Skiplist::Node's (although I haven't test its correctness). The memory part seems to be fixed for now, and I want to thank everyone here.
I would like to know if the trivialy-copyable part is actually relevant to the Skiplist implementation. There are no deep copies that need to be performed for skiplist (if that is what makes objects non-trivially copyable) but only need to copy pointer values. I will try out using std::vector.

@jho317 I would like to know if the trivialy-copyable part is actually relevant to the Skiplist implementation -- Vector<T>::Vector(size_t  size, const T& val) -- If T is not trivially-copyable, then you have to change your code, SkipList or no SkipList.  If you  debug and put a breakpoint on that line of code and the breakpoint is hit, then all bets are off if you have a SkipList<std::string>.  Remember that you explicitly coded all of your classes to take a T, and no restrictions on T are present in your code.  When you write template code, you have to be aware of these things.

@PaulMcKenzie May I know how that can be resolved at a higher level?

Use new[] and delete[], not malloc and free.

@PaulMcKenzie Oh I see. I guess it is because new/delete automatically deals with constructors too. Thank you I'll try working on it.

@jho317 The disadvantage of using new[] in this case is that the whole capacity of your vector gets constructed, when you only need construction upto the size of the vector. What std::vector does is allocate memory (using something like malloc) and then construct only the parts of that memory that need constructing using std::construct_at, and then the reverse on destruction, std::destroy_at followed by free.

please show a [mre]
